# Button class name are same for 2 buttons how to identify the elements

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

Button class name are same for 2 buttons how to identify the elements
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DcgLk.png)

[button clase naem rae same only the div class name are different](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iofXK.png)

Answer (score 0):

If that class really is the best way to identify those elements, I guess you might best do so by grabbing both elements with the class and differentiating them programmatically. I'm writing pseudocode since you haven't specified a coding language:

```
webelement array buttons = driver.findElementsByCss('button.ss-button.ss-button.ss-button--secondary')
firstButton = buttons[0]
secondButton = buttons[1]
```

Answer (score 0):

**xpath**

```
for first button: (//input[@class='your-class-name')[1]
for second button: (//input[@class='your-class-name')[2]
```

**css selector**

```
for first button: input[class='your-class-name']:nth-child(1)
for second button : input[class='your-class-name']:nth-child(2)
```

Java code:

```
WebElement button1 = _driver.findElements(By.cssSelector(".your-class-name")).get(0);

WebElement button2 = _driver.findElements(By.cssSelector(".your-class-name")).get(1);
```

Comment: Both the button name are same so its not working